# customized summary in proc report sas

Tags: sas

I need a report with a customized summary, the next report shows the fields in the test data set and the total results are the sum of each variable. I want the total value to be the total of the variable num divided by the total of the variable tot. i.e. 68/194 = 35.05%, and not the sum of the percentages in the rate variable.

```
data test;
input rank num tot rate;
datalines;
1 20 50 0.4
2 15 30 0.5
3 28 52 0.538461538461538
4 5 62 0.0806451612903226
;
run;

proc report data = _last_ box spacing = 1 split = "/"
    style(header) = [font_face = "courier new"] style(column) = [font_face = 
      "courier new"]
    style(lines) = [font_face = "courier new"] style(report) = [font_face = 
    "courier new"]
     style(summary) = [font_face = "courier new" font_style = roman]; 

   column(rank num tot rate);
   define rank        / " Rank " center         width = 6  format = 5. order 
        order = data;
   define num         / " N " center         width = 6  format = 5.;
   define tot         / " Total " center         width = 6  format = 5.;
   define rate        / " Rate " center         width = 6  format = 
    percent9.2 ;
   rbreak after / summarize style = [font_weight = bold];

 run;
```

[image]

Comment: Please post the output you're getting and what you want it to look like.

Comment: @user667489 Thanks, I just uploaded the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add compute block after summarize.

```
proc report data = _last_ box spacing = 1 split = "/"
    style(header) = [font_face = "courier new"] style(column) = [font_face = 
      "courier new"]
    style(lines) = [font_face = "courier new"] style(report) = [font_face = 
    "courier new"]
     style(summary) = [font_face = "courier new" font_style = roman]; 

   column(rank num tot rate);
   define rank        / " Rank " center         width = 6  format = 5. order 
        order = data;
   define num         / " N " center         width = 6  format = 5.;
   define tot         / " Total " center         width = 6  format = 5.;
   define rate        / " Rate "  center         width = 6  format = 
    percent9.2 ;

   rbreak after / summarize style = [font_weight = bold];
   compute after;
       rate.sum=num.sum/tot.sum;
   endcomp;
 run;
```

Comment: Thank you. That was just what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there - I think you just need to specify `analysis mean` when you `define` the variable `rate`:

```
data test;
input rank num tot rate;
datalines;
1 20 50 0.4
2 15 30 0.5
3 28 52 0.538461538461538
4 5 62 0.0806451612903226
;
run;

proc report data = _last_ box spacing = 1 split = "/"
    style(header) = [font_face = "courier new"] style(column) = [font_face = 
      "courier new"]
    style(lines) = [font_face = "courier new"] style(report) = [font_face = 
    "courier new"]
     style(summary) = [font_face = "courier new" font_style = roman]; 

   column(rank num tot rate);
   define rank        / " Rank " center width = 6  format = 5. order order = data;
   define num         / " N " center width = 6  format = 5.;
   define tot         / " Total " center width = 6  format = 5.;
   define rate        / " Rate " center width = 6  format = percent9.2 analysis mean;
   rbreak after / summarize style = [font_weight = bold];
 run;
 quit;
```

Comment: I did it with the compute block, but it did not work, the average does not work, because the result is 37.98% and the true value is 35.05%.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. In that case you may be better off pre-computing your stats in a data step and using `proc print` instead.